# guys any one out there am badly stuck in codeigniter 3 route

Tags: php

I want to translate this URL "http://domain.loc/controller/method/pram1/pram2"
in the route config file. please advise. your help will be highly appreciated.
my current setting in route file is as below.
    $route['class/method2/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'class/method2/$1/$2';
Please advise.
URL http://domain.loc/controller/method/catagory/offset 10
uri segment am getting from request is as under.
array (size=1)
  'P' => string '10' (length=2)

Comment: What is your actual problem and what you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: thanks for your comments am trying to get  2 pram in method for querying db. but get get these prams in method.

Comment: `404` error is getting now? Also what is your controller name?

Comment: thanks for your reply my controller name is post and method is index and want to pass 2 parameter one fo catagory and second for offset for pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `uri` in to get those values, You just need to specify which segment you want to retrieve

```
public function test()
{
  $seg3 =  $this->uri->segment(3);
  $seg4 =  $this->uri->segment(4);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply my controller name is post and method is index and want to pass 2 parameter one fo catagory and second for offset for pagination

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

`$route['class/method2/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'post/index/$1/$2';`

Eg: When someone browser the url `http://www.YOURSITE.com/class/method2/23/555` then it will route your `Post` controller then to `index` method.

You can access the variable `$catagory =  $this->uri->segment(3);` `$offset =  $this->uri->segment(4);`

See [Codeigniter routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) for more details.